# Attachment in Salesforce

Tags: custom-button, attachment

Having an attachment code

```
  <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2" id="block1">
   <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputLabel value="File:" for="file"/>
      <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Whenever i click the Attachment window opens and i can browse and add the file .

My requirement is that when i click the button again i should be able to see the file which was uploaded and add one more button to clear the file .

Can we retrieve the file which was added in before uploading the attachment .

Answer (score 0):

@Joy11 you would have to build custom functionality using javascript remoting and/or jquery to implement your requirements. The inputFile component will not be sufficient.

Comment: Can you please share the code if you have one